# VBA Fill 2D array with distinct ranges

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, range

I want to fill a 2D array with several named ranges that are not connected. The contain one column and a constant number of rows

Code:

```
Range("Range1").Select
LastRow = Selection.Rows.count

Dim data() as variant
Redim data(1 to 4,1 to LastRow)
data(1)=Range("Range1").value
data(2)=Range("Range2").value
data(3)=Range("Range3").value
data(4)=Range("Range4").value
```

It gives a subject out of range error, but I cannot work out why?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference both dimensions of your variant array. For example:

```
data(1, 1) = Range("Range1").value
```

---

As per your comments, I'd suggest you use a `Collection` instead

```
Dim data As Collection
Set data = New Collection

data.Add Range("Range1")
data.Add Range("Range2")
...

MsgBox data(1).Address 'returns the address of Range1
```

Comment: Don't you create a third dimension then? e.g. data(1,1)(3)

Comment: @AngeloBE Yes, but you don't get a subject out of range error. If you want to access the ranges in the traditional way then I'd suggest using a collection instead. See update for example

Comment: s/Subject/Subscript/ ;-)